# Google Pub/Sub to listen to multiple emails

Tags: gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

Looking to use Pub/Sub to [watch](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#watch_request) for new emails from many email addresses, tied to a single topic.

Doing this for emails owned by my account is easy, however I am looking to setup a flow where others can signup to my service, authenticate access to their Gmail account via some OAuth flow, then allow me to [watch](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#watch_request) for updates.

Delegate accounts is one way, however that is limited in some capacity. You can't watch `@gmail.com` from a non `@gmail.com` account, or the GSuite administrator could have delegation disabled outside of an org email.

Is there a way this can be done?

Comment: No comments on my answer?